# Related follow-up paper

Tags: publications, journals, paper-submission

I have published a paper earlier in a journal and would like to submit a continuation of research paper to build on the earlier paper's results. I was wondering how is the second paper identified as a follow up of the original.

Also, I have changed my name since (same co-authors), do I have to indicate this?

**Details**

The first paper contained a series of experimental and modelling results for a pure system, and the new paper will contain experimental and modelling results of non-pure versions of the original system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it builds on previous results, just cite that normally. You might want to link them by the title, but that isn't required.

It will be accepted for publication if it is significant enough. You might also consider publishing it elsewhere, if the outlook warrants it.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you would cite your earlier paper somewhere in the introduction of the new paper.  You could write something like this:

Recently, we (Author1, Author2, & Author3, 2016) presented a series of experimental and modelling results for a pure system.  With the current paper, we would like to extend ...

Alternatively, a footnote may be appropiate to indicate that the first authors are the same.

Also, see this publication on the topic of name changes in academia: [The Ripple Effect of Women's Name Changes](http://lib.dr.iastate.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1014&context=refinst_pubs)